# Import Data from Multiple Different Google Workbooks to One Master Workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to import data from 57 Google Sheets Files / Workbooks to one master Google Sheet.  For example, I have 57 teachers - each with their own Google Sheets document.  I use their document when I observe to collect data.  I need a way to grab the data I collected from each of their separate files, bring it into my master file and match it with their name in my sheet without having to use the IMPORTRANGE function for each one.  Is this possible with a script, or is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: If all of those documents are shared with you then you can access them with SpreadsheetApp.openById() and collect any data that you wish.  It should be very easy if you know how to use Google Apps Script.  I would probably preferred keeping their spreadsheet id's in a local file so that I could access of of their data in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (change id in the list)

```
const ids = [
  '1T7ixa-JGLgh8oZ19mWUy3Oo4UzbivflUlwL9zLGVkgg',
  '16uEeVNEBzBbGVTgKa98Ob7Wcy5mof9n6mU-yKIZ0fKM',
  '1d3ZHi1H0uUMU7jYsrwses66ULkmM4bFHyDn8RFtAlkk'
]
function myFunction() {
  let result = []
  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    let [headers, ...data] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues()
    if (i == 0) { result.push(headers.flat()) }
    data.forEach(r => result.push(r))
  })
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('myMasterSheet') 
  master.clearContents()
  master.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

you can use a sheet to store the IDs if necessary

Comment: Can you provide the format of your master sheet ? But I recommand to gather all informations in one sheet as is first and then work with them.

Comment: OK - no problem.  I will just add a tab to my master file to collect the data in one place.  Where do I indicate which cells to pull the data from?  Should there be cell references in the .getDataRange parenthesis?

Comment: The result will push into A1 and the cells below and to the right if needed. Make a trial and let me know if you want to adjust!

Comment: I added a tab to my Master Sheet and named it IMPORTS.  It will be fine for the data to go to that tab, but I'm still confused about how the script will know where to find the specific cell data from the teacher file.  It will need to go to that file, to the tab labeled "FALL OBS" and import cells A5 through M5.